# Debug Action Cable with Puma and Nginx configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

Action Cable works in development but doesn't work in production. I have no idea how to debug it or how to narrow down the problem. In production I use puma (3.12.0), Nginx (1.10.3), Redis (3.2.6) and Rails 5.2.2 (Ruby 2.5.3p105) on a Debian 9 system. Everything but Action Cable works fine.

The rails production log ends with these lines:

```
I, [...]  INFO -- : [ae5f4486-eadd-466d-a4de-fd8db3cdcfb4] Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
D, [...] DEBUG -- :   ESC[1mESC[36mUser Load (0.8ms)ESC[0m  ESC[1mESC[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT $1ESC[0m  [["LIMIT", 1]]
E, [...] ERROR -- : An unauthorized connection attempt was rejected
E, [...] ERROR -- : Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
I, [...]  INFO -- : Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-14 15:52:53 +0100
I, [...]  INFO -- : Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-14 15:52:53 +0100
I, [...]  INFO -- : [58aa5ff7-e440-4050-88b6-6e9dcdc691a0] Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-14 15:55:35 +0100
I, [...]  INFO -- : [58aa5ff7-e440-4050-88b6-6e9dcdc691a0] Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-14 15:55:35 +0100
I, [...]  INFO -- : [58aa5ff7-e440-4050-88b6-6e9dcdc691a0] Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
D, [...] DEBUG -- :   ESC[1mESC[36mUser Load (0.8ms)ESC[0m  ESC[1mESC[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT $1ESC[0m  [["LIMIT", 1]]
E, [...] ERROR -- : An unauthorized connection attempt was rejected
E, [...] ERROR -- : Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
I, [...]  INFO -- : Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-14 15:55:35 +0100
I, [...]  INFO -- : Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-14 15:55:35 +0100
```

Nginx configuration:

```
upstream my_app {
  server unix:/tmp/example.sock;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  # ... ssl configuration

  server_name xyz.example.com;

  root /var/www/example/current/public;

  location /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri @ruby;
  }

  location @ruby {
    proxy_pass http://my_app;

    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Ssl on; # Optional
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $host;

    proxy_redirect off;
  }

  location /cable {
    proxy_pass http://my_app;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }
}
```

In the `production.rb` I have these lines:

```
config.action_cable.url = 'wss://xyz.example.com/cable'
config.action_cable.disable_request_forgery_protection = true
```

**app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb**

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      # This is a websocket so we have no warden and no session here
      # How to reuse the login made with devise?
      # http://www.rubytutorial.io/actioncable-devise-authentication/
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    private

    def find_verified_user
      if verified_user = User.find_by(id: cookies.signed["user.id"])
        verified_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I don't see the `An unauthorized connection attempt was rejected` error in my development log so I guess that this must be the problem. But googling that phrase doesn't help.

How can I narrow down the problem?

Comment: i have similar config and nginx returns 301 for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like the ActionCable part is working, but there is an authentication error. `Successfully upgraded to WebSocket` means it opened a websocket connection with the user, but `An unauthorized connection attempt was rejected` is saying that you are rejecting their connection somewhere in your code.

Check your `connection.rb` file, are you calling `reject_unauthorized_connection` somewhere?

## A possible Fix

**app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb**

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    protected

      def find_verified_user
        if current_user = env['warden'].user
          current_user
        else
          reject_unauthorized_connection
        end
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: I added the connect of `connection.rb`. I copied that one from a how-to.

Comment: You must be right. When I replace the content of the `find_verified_user` method with a `User.find(5)` then I can use ActionCable for that user.

Comment: You have been a real life saver for me! Thank you so much. I added the fix to your answer.